# Do I need a visa for an EU journey leaving UK before and returning after Brexit?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, uk-citizens, brexit

May seen an obvious, but informations seems to be contradictory :

If Britain leaves the EU without a deal do we need a Visa for our holiday visit to Lanzarote Our trip spans the exit date 24th March to 4th April?

Comment: Please read the questions and answer under "[brexit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brexit)" tag. Informations seem contradictory because they are contracdictory. No one can know what would happen in case of hard brexit.

Comment: It is a complex interaction between European Union, Schengen Agreement and other deals that may or may not be involved and it was never tried in practice. It is impossible to say, so the only *safe* bet is to apply for visa - most of the time the fact that you do not *need* it does not prevent you from *applying* or *having* it.

Comment: @Mołot it's **impossible** to apply for a Schengen visa as an EU citizen, even though Britain might end up leaving soon.

Comment: @JonathanReez but Great Britain is not part of the Schengen treaty, is it? Do you have any source that shows it is really impossible?

Comment: @Mołot the Schengen area has nothing to do with it. EU citizens enjoy complete freedom of movement between EU member countries, it's the very basis of EU's single market. Issuing visas to EU citizens would thus run afoul against one of EU's main pillars.

Comment: @JonathanReez EU citizens do not *need* visa. I agree. Do you have any source they *can not* obtain one?

Comment: @Mołot no consulate website will explicitly spell it out because it is presumed to be obvious

Comment: So there is no source it is impossible, it is just your opinion based on lack of information, right?

Comment: @Mołot The Schengen Visa Code (Regulation EC 810/2009), which is the legal basis for issuing Schengen visa only applies to those actually needing a visa to enter (article 1, section 2). There is currently simply no legal basis for issuing Schengen visa to EEA or EU citizens and it is therefore not done. Just as you nowhere will find it explicitely spelled out that e.g. UK residence permits are not issued to UK citizens, you will also nowhere find it spelled out that Schengen visas are not issued to UK citizens.

Comment: As I understand it, UK citizens **cannot** get a Schengen visa before Brexit, and in the absolute worst case they might **need** one after Brexit. Problems like this is what the Brexit treaty is supposed to resolve, but it might not be signed. On the other hand, all the statements made by the EU27 sound as if UK citizens will not be penalized or deported immediately after Brexit.